# Jquery roundslider in angular 2/Ionic application

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic2, ionic3, typescript-typings

How to use  [http://roundsliderui.com/]  plugin in angular 2 /Ionic application 
already integrated jquery using typings.

 Since there is no typings available for this plugin, your support is appreciated

Answer (score 0):

To use jquery in ionic app

```
npm install jquery --save
```

then inside the page
add this import

```
import * as $ from "jquery";
```

Comment: jquery is integrated and working fine  roundsliderui is giving error